Change Webview URL via JavascriptInterface | Kotlin Android
I am trying to create a mobile app using WebView and what I want is to change the url of the current webview using the javascript interface. I am facing with an error saying " Uncaught Error: Java exception was raised during method invocation"
WebAppInterfaced.kt
package com.example.barangkalearninghub

import android.content.Context
import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
import android.webkit.WebView

class WebAppInterfaced(val webview: WebView) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun PageRedirect(newUri: String) {
        webview.loadUrl(newUri)
    }
}

main.kt
package com.example.barangkalearninghub

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient
import android.webkit.WebView
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat


@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        val webView:WebView = findViewById(R.id.webViewMain)
        webView.webChromeClient = WebChromeClient()
        WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true)
        val jsInterface:WebAppInterfaced = WebAppInterfaced(webView);
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "WebAppInterfaced")

        webView.settings.databaseEnabled = true
        webView.settings.allowFileAccess = true
        webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
        webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
    }


}

asset folder - > index.html
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    var p = $("#demo");
    p.html("hello jquery android");
    setTimeout(function(){
       WebAppInterfaced.PageRedirect("dashboard.html");
    }, 5000);
});

Is this even possible? How to change the webview via jsinterface?
It does not work. I tried outputting a string for testing if the jsinterface is really available and it work. However when I use the webview.loadurl it raises and error.

I finally found the solution
class WebAppInterfaced(val webview: WebView) {
    @JavascriptInterface
    fun PageRedirect(newUri: String) {
        webview.post(Runnable {
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/$newUri")
        });
    }

}

